# Lost list element in a concurrency program

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

This is a task from the book *Head First Java*, where the reader is asked to find out what happens in the following code block:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TwoThreadsWriting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Data data = new Data();
        threadPool.execute(()-> addLetterToData('a', data));
        threadPool.execute(()-> addLetterToData('A', data));
        threadPool.shutdown();
    }

    private static void addLetterToData(char letter, Data data) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
            data.addLetter(letter++);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + data.getLetters());
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " size: " + data.getLetters().size());
    }
}
class Data {
    private final List<String> letters = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<String> getLetters() {return letters;}
    public void addLetter(char letter){
        letters.add(String.valueOf(letter));
    }
}
```

I expected that the output lists contain 52 characters like this

```
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', ...]
```

But sometimes the number of elements is less than 52 and some characters are missing in `letters`, like here for example (`'K'` is missing):

```
pool-1-thread-2[A, a, B, b, c, C, d, D, e, E, f, F, G, g, H, h, i, I, J, j, k, L, l, m, M, N, n, O, o, p, P, q, Q, r, R, s, S, t, T, u, U, V, v, w, W, X, x, y, Y, Z, z]

pool-1-thread-1[A, a, B, b, c, C, d, D, e, E, f, F, G, g, H, h, i, I, J, j, k, L, l, m, M, N, n, O, o, p, P, q, Q, r, R, s, S, t, T, u, U, V, v, w, W, X, x, y, Y, Z, z]

pool-1-thread-2 size: 51
pool-1-thread-1 size: 51
```

I do not understand why this happens. I tried debugging it by printing the value of the local variable `letter` of `addLetter` but it only shows me that the `'K'` was actually added.

I do know that this all happens solely due to using the non-thread-safe `ArrayList` or `addLetter` not being declared as `synchronized`, but I want to understand what's even happening here in the first place.

Comment: You have a data race, which is a common issue when working on concurrent threads. **Concurrency is hard**.

Comment: Re, "...what's even happening." You'd have to look at the source code for `ArrayList` to know what's _really_ happening. But why not start with one of those examples where two threads increment a counter variable, and some of the increments get lost? An `ArrayList` basically is an array with a counter variable that tells where to `add` the next item.

Comment: Even looking at source won't clarify all of it, because in the absence of synchronization different optimizations like reordering of instructions are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is not thread-safe. If two threads try to call `add()` at the same time, anything might happen.
From the [Arraylist documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads
> access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the
> threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized
> externally.